# Install Iceweasel in Persistence (?)

Tags: tails, firefox, persistent

I'm interested in keeping all of my add-ons I install on Iceweasel to stay there for the next time I boot up Tails OS. I've tried Firefox sync but all it does is upload and will not restore to the Iceweasel instance. Is there any way to enable me to keep addons?

Possible things:

- Disable wiping of certain folder
- Install iceweasel in persistence drive
- Anything else?

Answer (score 1):

The Firefox profile is not part of Tails persistence framework for reasons related to upgrades and safety.

If it's only about the extensions, there might be a way though. If the [extensions are in Debian](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=xul-ext&searchon=names&suite=oldstable&section=all) you can use the [Additional software packages](https://tails.boum.org/doc/first_steps/persistence/configure/index.en.html#index13h2) feature of the persistence framework to install the extensions automatically.

Please note that any extensions might make your browser act differently and thus harm your anonymity. They might also leak sensitive information.